# Terminology used when a high note in a sentence is sung like a flasetto

Tags: voice, terminology

In many pop songs I've listened to, when the singer touches the high notes in a line, it is sung like a falsetto.

For example, in [this cover of **Hello** by Conor Maynard](https://youtu.be/rDWuqrJAyGw), the chorus starts from 1:14. Observe the capitalized part of the lines:

> Hello from the other siiiiidEEE''
>
> I must have called a thousand tiimesSSS
>
> To TELL you I'M sorrEYYYY

He increases the pitch at those capitalized words and the voice is like, 'smooth' and high pitched. I do not know how to describe that, but, you could get the idea.

I've heard these in Michael Jackson songs especially the parts where Jackson sings 'HeHe' or 'I'.

I simply called it as falsetto, but I have learnt that one cannot blend falsetto and chest voice, as falsetto requires the vocal chords to be disconnect and chest voice has them connected.

The guy in the video seems to 'blend' them, i.e., sings only the word with the highest note with that voice and the rest seems to be his chest voice.

What is the correct terminology used for this 'impulsive high pitched' singing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a pretty good ear; it often is difficult to identify which register singers are using for each note (or at least, it was for me when I was first learning). Yes, I believe you're right; **this is called falsetto**. I don't know where you got the idea that blending falsetto and chest voice is impossible, but I'll say that the singer is **mixing their chest voice and their falsetto (using both**, not necessarily blending them). I'd consider blending to be any effort to make the two distinct registers' tones more compatible, which is definitely possible, though difficult (and much more difficult for male voices, usually).